# To list private you tube videos in a web site using api

Tags: javascript, php, video

Is it possible to list my private youtube videos in [a] web site using youtube data api. If so, can any one post the full detailed code in JavaScript or Php (Java script is preferable). I have been trying to do this for a long time. If I am signed in to youtube, I am able to display both private and public videos in a channel by setting my parameter to true. But others can see only my public videos. Can anyone please make a suggestion?

Comment: In [a] website means what?  A website you are working on? Is making the videos public not an option?

Comment: @ Chris: Ya.. A web site i am working on.. I don't want any one else to view my videos other than who are using my website.. My web site have section where the user has to log in  to view videos. Those videos should only be visible on that page. I want user to see those videos every time when that user is on that page..